# Как дочерним div задать высоту родительского?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Как сделать, чтобы дивы с классом `services-box-bg`, принимали высоту родительского контейнера?
Почему не работает `height: 100%;`?

Html код:

```
<div class="row services-box">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="services-box-bg">
            <p>Монтаж ограждения любой формы и сложности</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="services-box-bg">
            <p>Устройство дренажа и канализации</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="services-box-bg">
            <p>Мощение тротуарной плиткой</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Css код:

```
.services-box{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.services-box p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.services-box-bg{
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Нужно явно задать высоту родителя

```
.services-box>div{
    height:1000px;
}
```

ну или использовать js

Comment: Если использовать height:1000px; то сильно все разъезжается. Получается просто страница с тремя очень длинными полосами...

Comment: ну 1000 это условно. height:100% - не будет работать если высота родителя не определена. Если задача сделать все колонки одинаковой высоты, то тут 2 варианта:   1) - дать фиксированный размер для .col-md-4  2) - использовать скрипт для выравнивания

Answer (score 2):

Можно применить `flex`. 
Получиться примерно так:

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.services-box{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.services-box-bg {
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    flex:1;
}
.services-box p{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='services-box'>
  <div class='services-box-bg'>
        <p>Монтаж ограждения любой формы и сложности</p>
  </div>
  <div class='services-box-bg'>
        <p>Устройство дренажа и канализации</p>
  </div>
<div class='services-box-bg'>
        <p>Мощение тротуарной плиткой</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLuz24w5/1/)**

Comment: Вопрос задан с тегом [tag:bootstrap], Ваше решение же его исключает)

Comment: @Rolandius не углядел про бутстрап. Но, думаю по запросу будут заходить люди ) пригодится надеюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы понять, почему не работает `height: 100%;` необходимо понять, как работает свойство `height`.

Можно узнать об этом из [спецификации](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property), если кратко, то:

1. когда родительский блок имеет значение `height`, то дочерний может использовать это значение при расчете высоты в процентах;
2. в ситуации, когда у родительского контейнера `height: auto;` (это значение по умолчанию), то внутренний блок будет игнорировать это и не видеть высоту родительского;
3. если родительский блок имеет `position: absolute`, то внутренний блок будет иметь высоту 0, если он сам не имеет `position: absolute;`.

К сожалением, используя Bootstrap и его *grid*, сделать это достаточно проблематично, учитывая то, что на меленьких экранах блоки должны быть друг под другом. Без последнего требования можно найти выход, но зачем же тогда использовать Bootstrap?

Можно попробовать задать фиксированную высоту контейнеру `div.services-box`, но это откровенно говоря неудобно. Поэтому адекватным решением будет использовать JS в этой ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько техник для "[колонок одинаковой высоты](https://www.google.ru/search?q=css%20equal%20height%20columns)". Например, вы можете воспользоваться свойством [display: table-cell](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height).

```
.services-box {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.services-box>div {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что равная высота у блоков первой вложенности следом за `services-box`, а не у `services-box-bg`!

Comment: Это всё здорово, конечно, но попробуйте свернуть ваше окно. Стоит заметить, что метка у вопроса: [tag:bootstrap], Ваш же код приводит к уходу от него.

Comment: Думаю, автор разберется насколько это подходит для его ситуации. По ссылке откроется еще 100500 рецептов и ни один не идеален. И, слава макаронам, `bootstrap` не запрещает добавлять свои правила :)